# Custom IComparer in LINQ OrderBy Lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have a custom comparer I want to use with OrderBy. I am trying to build a LINQ expression to make it work. So in essence, I am trying to put together an IComparer, OrderBy inLinq expression.

The expression I am trying to build should look something like:

```
source => source.OrderBy(lambdaParameter => lambdaParameter.Name, new Parsers.NumericComparer()).
```

With the code below the expression

```
'{source => source.OrderBy(lambdaParameter => lambdaParameter.Name)}'
```

is built and I am trying to add this custom Icomparable to this expression

```
new Parsers.NumericComparer().
```

This is because I need to do a natural sort. Can someone please help me on how to include this expression. I am trying to read several threads for the past few hours but I have not done understood LINQ expressions well enough yet to implement this. Thanks!

```
private void CreateOrderByMethod(PropertyDescriptor prop, string orderByMethodName, string cacheKey)
{
    /*
     Create a generic method implementation for IEnumerable<T>.
     Cache it.
    */
    var sourceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>), "source");
    var lambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "lambdaParameter");

    var accesedMember = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);
    var propertySelectorLambda =
        Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(lambdaParameter, accesedMember), lambdaParameter);

    var orderByMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                                  .Where(a => a.Name == orderByMethodName &&
                                               a.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                  .Single()
                                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>(
                                Expression.Call(orderByMethod,
                                        new Expression[] { sourceParameter, 
                                                       propertySelectorLambda }),
                                        sourceParameter);
    cachedOrderByExpressions.Add(cacheKey, orderByExpression.Compile());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an expression that creates a new instance of an object, use [Expression.New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.new.aspx).

```
var newParser = Expression.New(typeof(Parsers.NumericComparer));
```

Then I suggest you use this overload of [Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107.aspx) instead, so that you don't have to go and manually grab the MethodInfo:

```
var orderByCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "OrderBy",
    new [] { typeof(T), prop.PropertyType },
    sourceParameter, propertySelectorLambda, newParser);
```